# Find and replace in string re.insensitive

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this code to find matches in a string, im using in a search to mark the wordds that match my search, i need this to be case insensitive, the issue here is that it replaces the word by the one we search.

```
val_to_searchp = "this Text string has alot of teXt"
word = "TEXT"
    
pal2rep = str(":::")+word+str(":::")
val_to_search = re.sub(re.escape(word), pal2rep, val_to_searchp, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
```

this will return

```
"this :::TEXT::: string has alot of :::TEXT:::"
```

I need it to return

```
"this :::Text::: string has alot of :::teXt:::"
```

Also tryed with this but its not working very well :(

```
f = 0
s = 0
val_to_search = val_to_searchp
for m in re.finditer(str(word), str(val_to_searchp)):
      inicio = int(m.start()+s)
      fim = int(m.end()+f)
                
      val_to_search = val_to_search[:inicio] \
             + str(":::") \
             + val_to_search[inicio:fim] \
             + str(":::") \
             + val_to_search[fim:].strip()

      f = f+2
      s = s+1
```

This is my actuall code

```
def findtext():
    if len(str(findtext_inp.get('1.0', END)))>1:
        val_to_searchp = str(respon_txt.get(1.0, END).replace(html.unescape('&#x26D4;'), "").strip())
        respon_txt.delete(1.0, END)
        word = str(findtext_inp.get('1.0', END).strip())

        pal2rep = str(str(html.unescape('&#x26D4;'))+word+str(html.unescape('&#x26D4;')))
        val_to_search = re.sub(re.escape(word), pal2rep, val_to_searchp, flags=re.IGNORECASE)


        """
        f = 0
        s = 0
        for m in re.finditer(str(word), str(val_to_search)):
            inicio = int(m.start()+s)
            fim = int(m.end()+f)
        
            val_to_search = val_to_search[:inicio] \
                + str(html.unescape('&#x26D4;')) \
                + val_to_search[inicio:fim] \
                + str(html.unescape('&#x26D4;')) \
                + val_to_search[fim:].strip()

            f = f+2
            s = s+1
        """


    respon_txt.insert(1.0, val_to_search)#val_to_search.replace(findtext_inp.get('1.0', END).strip() , str(html.unescape('&#x26D4;')+findtext_inp.get('1.0', END).strip())+html.unescape('&#x26D4;')))
```

Comment: Can you post actual code that you've run? The syntax errors in the code shown will stop this from working

Comment: mkrieger1 its str(":::") sorry

Comment: So you actually want to *insert* something *around* the match, not *replace* the match?

Comment: @MisterMyagi yes, i thought that replace would be the easier way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a rewrite of my original answer. In the comments for that answer you will see that the OP has changed his mind about how this needs to work. This now (hopefully) complies with the altered specification:

```
val_to_searchp = '''{\"configurationKey\":[{\"key\":\"GetMaxKeys\",\"readonly\":true,\"value\":\"20\"}'''
text = 'GetMaxKeys'

def func(s, txt):
    result = []
    sl = s.lower()
    txt = txt.lower()
    lt = len(txt)
    offset = 0
    while (i := sl[offset:].find(txt)) >= 0:
        result.append(s[offset:i+offset])
        offset += i
        result.append(f':::{s[offset:offset+lt]}:::')
        offset += lt
    result.append(s[offset:])
    return ''.join(result)

print(func(val_to_searchp, text))
```

**Output:**

```
{"configurationKey":[{"key":":::GetMaxKeys:::","readonly":true,"value":"20"}
```

Comment: this one didnt work, manage to make it work with some replaces, its uggly but it gets the job done. thank you so much for everything

Answer (score 2):

I'm sure there's a way to do this with RE but it's really trivial without the aid of that module.

```
val_to_searchp = "this Text string has alot of teXt\nThis also has a lot of text"
text = 'TEXT'

def func(s, txt):
    txt = txt.lower()
    result = []
    for line in s.split('\n'):
        for i, e in enumerate(t := line.split()):
            if e.lower() == txt:
                t[i] = f':::{e}:::'
        result.append(' '.join(t))
    return '\n'.join(result)

print(func(val_to_searchp, text))
```

**Output:**

```
this :::Text::: string has alot of :::teXt:::
This also has a lot of :::text:::
```

Comment: Any way to keep the order? if i have 3 lines in text it will join everything in one line, i need it to keep the 3 lines of text

Comment: @ralphgz Answer edited to support multiline strings

Comment: perfect, worked perfect with text, but unfortunally now i tested with real case and i notioce that there are no space and its not working  :(.

Comment: real case:  {\"configurationKey\":[{\"key\":\"GetMaxKeys\",\"readonly\":true,\"value\":\"20\"}

Comment: if i type GetMaxKeys it doesnt find anything :(

Comment: @ralphgz My suggested answer will not work with your "real case". It was designed to work with the data input and output given in your question

Comment: @ralphgz I will add another answer to suit the changed requirement

Comment: solve it with line = line.replace(":", " : ")
                            line = line.replace("\\", " \ ")
                            line = line.replace(",", " , ")
                            line = line.replace('"', ' " ')
                            line = line.replace(':', ' : ')

Comment: adding this after the for and in the end return '\n'.join(result).replace(" ","").  its not prety but it does wat i need